# Autocompleting UITextField crashes app

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have created a custom UITextField that compares user input against database records. Everything works great until the user puts a space in the text field after I have already suggested something. It crashes the app with the following message:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString substringToIndex:]: Range or index out of bounds'

Here is the code:

```
NSRange cursorRange = [[self valueForKey:@"selectionRange"] rangeValue];
NSString *entered = [self.text substringToIndex:cursorRange.location];
if (![self.text isEqualToString:entered]) {
    self.text = entered;
    return;
}

NSString *suggestedSuffix;
for (NSString *name in filterData) {
    if (name.length > cursorRange.location && [[name lowercaseString] hasPrefix:entered]) {
        suggestedSuffix = [name substringFromIndex:cursorRange.location];
        NSMutableString *suggestedString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:entered];
        [suggestedString appendString:suggestedSuffix];
        self.text = suggestedString;
        [self setValue:[NSValue valueWithRange:cursorRange] forKey:@"selectionRange"];
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I would suggest adding an NSLog after retrieving your NSRange and outputting the current value to determine what it's returning and why it's outside of the bounds of the text in the textfield..

Comment: Which line is throwing the error? Does the code you've shown get called for every character entered?

Comment: Code is fired by Control Event UIControlEventEditingChanged. So yes every character entered calls it again.

Comment: ERROR LOG PLEASE. I'm wondering if it's an NSInternalInconsistency exception caused by modifiying the UI while it is being updated by the UI subsystem itself...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering whether you have your key correct?

`UITextField` does not have a `selectionRange` property publicly defined AFAICT.  However, `<UITextInput>` - to which `UITextField` conforms - has a `selectedTextRange` property.  Is this perhaps what you intended?  (It's possible there's an undocumented private property actually called `selectionRange` that you've accidentally encountered, and which doesn't behave as expected in cases such as you encountered.)

Alternatively, did you really mean `UITextView` - which has a `selectedRange` - but still no `selectionRange`?

On a separate note, I don't think subclassing `UITextField` is the right approach here. Autocompletion can be completely (no pun intended) implemented using the `<UITextFieldDelegate>` methods and it is a maxim of Cocoa programming that when you can accomplish a goal through class composition rather than subclassing, you should opt for composition every time.

Comment: Ok, I was considering rethinking using <UITextFieldDelegate> anyway, so I will just start there. Thanks for the input.